# Update a table after inserting records with an Inner Join

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-update

I insert into TableA using a Select/Inner Join from TableB and TableC.

```
Insert into TableA (C,S,M,C100)
SELECT C,S,M,group_concat(CID) FROM TableB
INNER JOIN TableC
ON TableB.CID= TableC.CID and P>=100  group by C,S,M
```

Now I need to update those records in two ways. One is identical to the first but now I want to update a different field with P<100, in essence:

```
Insert into TableA (C,S,M,C0)
SELECT C,S,M,group_concat(CID) FROM TableB
INNER JOIN TableC
ON TableB.CID= TableC.CID and P<100  group by C,S,M
```

Except I don't want new records I want to update where TableA C,S,M match

The second thing I want to do is similar, but involves updating from a different table but in almost an identical manner

```
Insert into TableA (C,S,M,C100)
SELECT C,S,M,group_concat(CID) FROM TableD
INNER JOIN TableE
ON TableD.CID= TableD.CID and P>=100  group by C,S,M
```

In other words I could create each pass as separate inserts but would end up with duplicate records of C,S,M.

Is there a way to do the passes after the first insert as Updates OR is there a way to do them each as Inserts and afterwards combine the records where C,S,M are identical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an update with join :

```
UPDATE TableA 
join (select C,S,M,group_concat(CID) as newCol
      FROM TableB
      where P<100
      group by C,S,M) t
 ON (tableA.c = t.c and tableA.s = t.s and TableA.M = t.m)
SET <YourColumn> = t.newCol
```

Comment: Thank you. This might seem like a silly question but I was not able to make it work either (new to join); assume I no longer need to join B to C, I just want to update TableA with TableB Field,group_concat with the same ON conditions and group. I've tried and failed so something about this isn't making sense to me (yet), clarification on how to update would be appreciated.

Comment: No problem @user3649739. If you had posted your attempt I could have told you were you gone wrong, anyway I've updated the answer